# Convolution neural network predicts the probability of a class

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

For this [example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network.py), I tried to print out "tf.argmax(pred, 1)", and result is [1 3 4 1 2].

How to know the probability of the forecast category?
Does Tensorflow provide any API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is get the argmax of the prediction, and get the prediction at this index. 
This is all easier in numpy (for example, using the amax function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html)

```
tfpredicted,loss, acc = sess.run([pred,cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,y: batch_y,keep_prob: 1.})
print(np.amax(tfpredicted))
```

I did not test the code, but hope it works. Otherwise you might have to look at the max functions numpy offers.

Good luck!

Comment: So you mean the result of "pred" is all label probability.

But result is [[-11511043.  5100159.  5619258.  -1942...] [....]].

How to convert to probability?

Comment: not probability, but activation... did you already train your network?
And you could use a softmax function to get everything between 0 and 1 ;)

Comment: I thought it was 0 to 1, but result is [3365887.   4442517.    0.    4042083.25     0.].  I use that example(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)